# gdal_translate or gdalwarp to define projection

Tags: coordinate-system, gdalwarp, gdal-translate

Which of these is the best approach to define (AKA. set) a projection for a tiff?

1) `gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:32182 in.tif out.tif`

2) `gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:32182 -t_srs EPSG:32182 in.tif out.tif`

Comment: geotifcp instead?

Comment: This looks like a good utility but I wanted to stick with gdal.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you want to **set** the projection of a file with gdal tools, you should use [gdal_edit.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_edit.html) -a_srs

Both gdalwarp and gdal_translate will create a new file.